# sass no aplica los cambios a la hoja de estilos

Tags: css, html5, sass

no puedo hacer que los cambios que realizo  en la hoja de estilos se apliquen a mi proyecto, los archivos estan bien linkeados dejo el html
Puedo asegurar que la hoja de sass esta bien linkeada ya que la mayoria de los cambios si se aplica, solo que en el H2 no puedo

```
` <section class="container-fluid" id="contenedor-cartas-index">
    <h2 class="titulos">Consigue lo ultimo!</h2>
    <div class="contenedor-front">
        <div class="contenedor-tarjetas-front">
            <div class="card" style="width: 13rem;">
                <img src="assets/tapa1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" style="width: 13rem;">
                <img src="assets/tapa10.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" style="width: 13rem;">
                <img src="assets/tapa11.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" style="width: 13rem;">
                <img src="assets/tapa2.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>`


El siguiente archivo es mi archivo de SASS

    #contenedor-cartas-index{
    h2{
        text-align: center;
        color: red;
    }
    .contenedor-front{
        margin-top: 15px;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        .contenedor-tarjetas-front{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
}
}
    .card{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin: 10px;
        justify-content: center;
    }
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer, al menos en un principio es darle estilos al H2 los cuales no se estarian aplicando, por ejemplo centrarlo o darle formato

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no estas viendo una version en cache de la pagina no?

Comment: @gbianchi lo probe, apretando ctrl f5 despues de cada cambio que hago y no se compila. Tengo que darle init al sass cada vez que abra el proyecto?

Comment: 1. Si estas ejecutando sass con una linea de comando al final agregale --watch para que se ejecute ante cualquier cambio en tu hoja sass, aqui la [doc. oficial](https://sass-lang.com/guide/)

Comment: sass : No se puede cargar el archivo C:\Users\ignac\AppData\Roaming\npm\sass.ps1. El archivo C:\Users\ignac\AppData\Roaming\npm\sass.ps1 no está firmado digitalmente. No se puede 
ejecutar este script en el sistema actual. Para obtener más información acerca de la ejecución de scripts y la configuración de la directiva de ejecución, consulta 
about_Execution_Policies en https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ sass --watch
+ ~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess @Jimmy

Comment: Cuando hago los cambios directamente desde la hoja de style css si me deja aplicar los cambios y verlos en el navegador

Comment: Tengo que darle init a sass cada vez que voy a abrir el proyecto? lo instale anteayer y funcionaba